# Error in restoring BAK to MDF file

Tags: c#, sql-server, restore

I'm using following code to restore a BAK file to an MDF file, initially I create a database and then try to restore it using my BAK file, but I get some errors:
I use an open file dialog to select my BAK file

```
            openDialogConvert.ShowDialog();
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
        String[] instances = (String[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");
        string sqlname = "";
        if (instances.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (String element in instances)
            {
                if (element == "MSSQLSERVER")
                    sqlname = System.Environment.MachineName;
                else
                    sqlname = System.Environment.MachineName + @"\" + element;

            }
        }


        String str;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=" + sqlname + ";Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
        string dbname = "tmpDB" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        str = "CREATE DATABASE " + dbname + " ON PRIMARY " +
            "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
            "FILENAME = '" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + dbname + ".mdf') " +
            "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
            "FILENAME = '" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + dbname + ".ldf') ";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        myCommand.Dispose();

        str = @"RESTORE DATABASE [" + dbname + "] FROM  DISK = N'" + openDialogConvert.FileName + @"' WITH  MOVE N'IODB_Data' 
TO N'" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\\" + dbname + @".mdf',  MOVE N'IODB_Log' 
TO N'" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\\" + dbname + @".ldf',  REPLACE ";
            myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCommand.Dispose();
            myConn.Close();
```

my new (empty) database is created successfully but I get strange errors while trying to restore the BAK file in this newly created database.

I get following error using the above code:

> The operating system returned the error '32(failed to retrieve text
>   for this error. Reason: 15105)' while attempting
>   'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'D:\7 mordad
>   fara\Ofogh-Dsk\Ofogh-Dsk\bin\Debug\tmpDB635107927412887254.mdf'.
>
> File 'IODB_Data' cannot be restored to 'D:\7 mordad
>   fara\Ofogh-Dsk\Ofogh-Dsk\bin\Debug\tmpDB635107927412887254.mdf'. Use
>   WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> The operating system returned the error '32(failed to retrieve text
>   for this error. Reason: 15105)' while attempting
>   'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'D:\7 mordad
>   fara\Ofogh-Dsk\Ofogh-Dsk\bin\Debug\tmpDB635107927412887254.ldf'.
>
> File 'IODB_Log' cannot be restored to 'D:\7 mordad
>   fara\Ofogh-Dsk\Ofogh-Dsk\bin\Debug\tmpDB635107927412887254.ldf'. Use
>   WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.

RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

but when I insert a 'GO' at the end my command, I get following error:
Incorrect syntax near GO

what is going wrong here?
of course I've tested the restore operation successfully with SQL server management studio and I've found correct logical names for my BAK file (in fact I've copied the script from MSSMS)

Comment: OS error 32 means the system can't access the file because it is being used by another process. Are there any other programs open with a handle to the database files?

Comment: You mean BAK file or newly created MDF file?

Comment: The MDF and LDF files, the error refers to these files =]

Comment: I don't think so, as you can see my MDF file is dynamically created, how can I find that it is being referenced?

Comment: You could try using a tool called Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and filter on the generated file name. Your database files will also be in use by the SQL server. Restore should force any connections to be closed but you could try to take the database offline and put it back online again after the restore: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/24/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-take-database-offline-take-database-online/

Comment: I made my database offline, but again the same error occurs

Comment: Ok so if you download process monitor, put a breakpoint after your database is created and then use process monitor to filter for that file name and see if there are any processes trying to access it, that might give you a better idea as to what is going on.

Comment: It looks like Environment.CurrentDirectory points to the bin\Debug folder. I'd bet SQL Server doesn't have access to that location. Do you really want your data and log files restored there?

Comment: location is not really important I just want to have them somewhere in my hard disk!

Comment: I changed restore location to c:\ but again no luck

Comment: You won't be able to restore to the root of the c drive either. It will need to be some place where the user that the service runs as has permissions.

Comment: well I changed it to d:\, but again no luck, can you give me a sample location? should I explicitly give permission to a path?

Comment: Don't restore to the root of any drive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34452/discussion-between-ali-dotnet-and-brian)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

- Step 1 - connect the database server using MS SQL Server Management
  Studio.
- step 2 - Find the database in the left pane & right-click to choose
  the restore option.
- Step 3 - Choose the destination and source for restoration.
- Step 4 - Browse for the backup file from the device & click on ok
- Step 5 - Select the database you want to restore from the list and
  click ok.

After completing the restore process, your database will be ready to use.

Note: You must create a new database to restore the old one.